# Grid view scrolling is not smooth

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

I am using GridView to show the images, which are stored in the device in SD card. When I scroll the GridView, the scrolling is not smooth. The getview function of the customAdapter is as follows:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_xml, parent, false);

   ImageView photo= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.gImage);
   DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
   getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
   int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
   photo.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width/2, width/2));

   final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
   options.inSampleSize = 2;
   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageUrls.get(position).getimageUrl(), options);
   photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

   return view;
}
```

Where imageUrl is the arrayList of the strings which are the location of the images in the Sd card. Also I am setting the width and height of the ImageView dynamically.

Comment: please read the documentation http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: 1. you are not reusing the convertView 2. you are decoding bitmap on main thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing disk I/O on the main application thread, in the form of your `decodeFile()` call. This will give you performance problems.

There are a many image loading libraries, like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) and [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). Please use one of those. They will load your image in the background and populate your `ImageView` when the image is ready. If you insist on rolling your own code for this, use `AsyncTask` or other background threading for your disk I/O.

Beyond that, as Selvin notes in the comments, please pay attention to the `convertView` parameter to `getView()` and do not blindly inflate a layout when it is not needed.